# Retrieving selected value from dropdown laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, html-select

I am having trouble with something really simple. I am trying to get the selected value of a dropdownlist.

DD list

```
<select name="category_id" class="form-control selectpicker" >
            <option value=" " >Kategori Seçiniz</option>
            <option values="1">first category</option>
            <option values="2">second</option>
            <option values="3">third </option>
    </select>
```

I can get the value with the code below. I don`t see why

```
Input::get('category_id');
```

Comment: Please show use the code in your controller

Comment: What does $request["category_id"] return?

Comment: Your options are using the attribute `values`. It should be `value`, like the first option.

Comment: thank you, it was a copy paste mistake but was driving me crazy

Comment: @rematnarab No problem. Since this wasn't just a typo in the question, I posted an answer so you can mark this question solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your options are using the attribute `values`. The attribute should be `value`.